# Need help making an ArrayList Add At in C

Tags: c, arraylist, addition

I'm not sure how to add to the list at a specific index with *arrlist_addat*. I included some of my other methods and my struct so you can see how I'm doing it. The method must return a boolean true if it adds it and false if it fails.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

```
struct ArrayList {
    void** arr;
    int size;
    int maxSize;
    int itemSize;
    char* type;
};

struct ArrayList* arrlist_initialize(int maxSize, int itemSize, char* dataType) {
    struct ArrayList* list = malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayList));
    list->size = 0;
    list->maxSize = maxSize;
    list->itemSize = itemSize;
    list->type = dataType;
    list->arr = NULL;
    return list;
}

bool arrlist_add(struct ArrayList* list, void* element) {
    void** data = realloc(list->arr, sizeof(*list->arr));
    if (data == NULL)
        return false;
    data[list->size] = element;
    list->arr = data;
    list->size = list->size+1;
    return true;
}

bool arrlist_addat(struct ArrayList* list, int index, void* element) {

    //Need help here.

}

void* arrlist_get(struct ArrayList* list, int index) {
    void* value = list->arr[index];
    if (value != NULL)
        return value;
    return NULL;
}

int arrlist_index_of(struct ArrayList* list, void* element) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list->size; ++i) {
        if (element == arrlist_get(list, i))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `void** data = realloc(list->arr, sizeof(*list->arr));` looks bad. It should be `void** data = realloc(list->arr, sizeof(*list->arr) * (list->size + 1));`

Comment: 1. Add a dummy element (maybe `NULL`) at the end of array 2. Shift elements of array afte the point to insert 3. Store value to insert

Comment: `alist_get` used in `arrlist_index_of()` is not defined here. Do you mean `arrlist_get`?

Comment: yeah that should be arrlist_get

Comment: Is `arrlist_addat` supposed to *insert* an element (moving the existing elements up by one index) or *overwrite* an element? Also, can `index` be greater than `list-size` requiring additional `NULL` elements to be inserted?

Comment: It's supposed to insert an element and move the rest. And the index can't be greater than the list-size it would then return false cause it can't add it.

Comment: Also, why does `arrlist_initialize` allocate two elements and set the first one to `NULL`? It could just set `list->arr = NULL;` since `realloc` still works OK if the original pointer is `NULL`.

Comment: Going to be honest idk this is my first time doing arraylists in C so I was kind of winging it, now looking at it again it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: In arrlist_initialize would I even need to have a null element for it to work or could I just take out 2 list->arr lines?

Comment: Well, the edited version has a memory leak: `list->arr = calloc(1, sizeof(void*));` followed by `list->arr = NULL;`. Just remove the `calloc` line to avoid the leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the length of the array is *maxSize*, you just shift the elements to the right before inserting the element, like this:

```
bool arrlist_addat(struct ArrayList* list, int index, void* element)
{
    bool done;
    int i;

    assert(list != NULL);
    
    if ((list->size < list->maxSize) && (index >= 0) && (index <= list->size)) {
        /*make room for the new element*/
        for (i = list->size; i > index; i--) {
            list->arr[i] = list->arr[i - 1];
        }
        
        list->arr[index] = element;     
        list->size++;
        done = true;
    } else {
        done = false;
    } 
    return done;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stated requirement is that `arrlist_addat` should insert an element at the given index that cannot be greater than the current size.  So after checking the requirement, the function just needs to reallocate the memory that holds the array/list of `void *` values, shuffle up the `void *` values from the given index onwards up by one, and set write the inserted `void *` value to the indexed location.

Assuming the implementation has an optimized `memmove` function, that would probably be the quickest way to shuffle up the existing elements.  Here is a sample implementation:

```
bool arrlist_addat(struct ArrayList* list, int index, void* element) {
    void** data;
    if (index > list->size)
        return false;
    data = realloc(list->arr, sizeof(*list->arr) * (list->size + 1));
    if (!data)
        return false;
    memmove(&list->arr[index + 1], &list->arr[index], (list->size - index) * sizeof(*list->arr));
    list->arr[index] = element;
    list->size++;
    return true;
}
```

`arrlist_add` can be implemented using `arrlist_addat`:

```
bool arrlist_add(struct ArrayList* list, void* element) {
    return arrlist_addat(list, list->size, element);
}
```

ASIDE: `arrlist_get` should probably check the index and return `NULL` if out of range:

```
void* arrlist_get(struct ArrayList* list, int index) {
    if (index >= list->index)
        return NULL;
    // Should we also check for negative indices here?
    // It's probably better to use unsigned indices anyway!
    return list->arr[index];
}
```

Comment: I ignored `list->maxSize` because the original code ignores it too. But it is easy enough to add a check for exceeding `list->maxSize` if required.

Comment: In your implementation the result is undefined upon success.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Thanks. I forgot the `return true;` at the end. I'll add that now.

Comment: If you use for instance the GCC compiler, the flag `-Wall` will catch this.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom The problem is, I didn't bother compiling it. :)